# Using for loop inside forEach array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Please take a look at the code below.

I have a main array: *nop*
and a temp array: *tempArray*

If the tempArray array contains elements that are in the main array nop, then mark its *isSelect* as true.

However, if you run the code below, you will see only the last element of tempArray as been changed on the main array nop....

```
var nop = [
    {title:'blue', isSelect: false },
    {title:'red', isSelect: true },
    {title:'yellow', isSelect: false },
    {title:'black', isSelect: false },
    {title:'dark blue', isSelect: false },
    {title:'reddish', isSelect: false },
    {title:'hello', isSelect: false },
    {title:'help', isSelect: false },
    {title:'me', isSelect: false }
];

var tempArray = ["blue", "hello", "help"];

tempArray.forEach(function(value){
                var index;
                for (index = 0; index < nop.length; ++index) {
                    if (nop[index].title === value){
                        nop[index].isSelect = true;
                        console.log('FOR LOOP = TRUE for: ' + value);
                    }
                    else {
                        nop[index].isSelect = false;
                    }
                }
            });

console.log(JSON.stringify(nop));
```

The above results in :

```
FOR LOOP = TRUE for: blue
FOR LOOP = TRUE for: hello
FOR LOOP = TRUE for: help
[{"title":"blue","isSelect":false},{"title":"red","isSelect":false},{"title":"yellow","isSelect":false},{"title":"black","isSelect":false},{"title":"dark blue","isSelect":false},{"title":"reddish","isSelect":false},{"title":"hello","isSelect":false},{"title":"help","isSelect":true},{"title":"me","isSelect":false}]
```

Only this element was updated:  `{"title":"help","isSelect":true}`

I want to get all 3 elements updated:

```
{"title":"blue","isSelect":true} 
{"title":"yellow","isSelect":true}
{"title":"help","isSelect":true}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each colour you are overriding the previous result because of the "else" set them all to false first then loop and set the ones you want to true

```
        tempArray.forEach(function(value){
            var index;
            for (index = 0; index < nop.length; index++) {
                if (nop[index].title === value){
                    nop[index].isSelect = true;
                    console.log('FOR LOOP = TRUE for: ' + value);
                }

            }
        });
```

js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rxq529s4/

Comment: Everyone had the right answer, but the little explanation helped me understand. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you require nested loops for this. Check my answer once.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `else` condition

```
tempArray.forEach(function(value){
                var index;
                for (index = 0; index < nop.length; ++index) {
                    if (nop[index].title === value){
                        nop[index].isSelect = true;
                        console.log('FOR LOOP = TRUE for: ' + value);
                    }

                }
            });
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/Ljpazsr4/)**

**EDIT**

```
for (index = 0; index < nop.length; ++index) 
               if (tempArray.indexOf(nop[index].title)) 
                      nop[index].isSelect = true;

console.log(JSON.stringify(nop));
```

Answer (score 0):

While looping with `forEach` the second loop erases the changes from the first one as your else case set `isSelect` to **false** if the title is not the current value.

You should check if `isSelected` is **true** in your for block and skip title equals value section.

Answer (score 0):

You are making the unmatched one false in else part. So, only the last one is updated and then not changed. Remove the else part.